# MS Access 2016: When TabControl tab regains focus, requery listbox

Tags: ms-access, tabcontrol

I have a `Tab Control` element containing 2 tabs: Tab1 and Tab2. Tab2 contains a `ListBox` element whose `RowSource` queries the data that gets submitted in Tab1.

Say the user opens this form containing these 2 tabs. They are originally on Tab1. in the `Form_Load` event for Tab2, it queries the data it needs to populate its `ListBox`. Now they switch tabs to Tab1. They enter some data and submit a new record to the corresponding table (the same table that the Tab2 ListBox uses as its `RowSource`). When the user switches back to Tab2, they don't see this newly added record.

What I have done so far is that when the user clicks anywhere in the ListBox, it calls `Requery`, and then the record will show up. This isn't enough as it's not intuitive for the user to have to click on the listbox to update its contents.

I have tried putting this `Requery` code in a Form_Load, Form_Activate, GotFocus, but nothing works. I know you can detect the TabControl clicks, but how can I access the forms and the elements that they contain?

Any ideas on how to requery this listbox whenever the tab gains control?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add code for a specific tab on a tabcontrol, the most convenient way to do that is to write code in the `TabCtl_Change` event. That occurs when the tab control is changed. E.g.:

```
Private Sub MyTabCtl_Change()
    If MyTabCtl.Pages(MyTabCtl.Value).Name = "Tab2" Then 'The tab control just changed to your page
        'Requery that list box
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that, if you're not using a tab control at all, but a navigation control (which it does sound like, tab controls don't necessarily have subforms on them, and don't have `Form_Load` events, forms do)

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely looking for the `On Activate` trigger.

Then, in the code just use `Form.Requery` or `Form.Recalc` depending on which you're actually looking to do.

Alternatively, you could use the same control the user is using to submit records to trigger a requery. Although, that would require a specific `Form` to be called into focus.